# GAE: Flask/webassets throws an expection on {% extends "base.html" %}

Tags: google-app-engine, flask, webassets, flask-assets

I am trying to port my existing flask app into google app engine. After a lot of reading and solving issues, I came across a problem I am completely stuck with:

Upon starting the app on my local environment, I get this error message:

**Short version:**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
OSError: [Errno 38] Function not implemented
```

How can this function not be implemented? It is part of flask/jinja2.

**Longer version:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>
ERROR    2013-06-17 14:26:42,772 app.py:1306] Exception on / [GET]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kave/eclipse/F11/Engineering/flask/app.py", line 1687, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/home/kave/eclipse/F11/Engineering/flask/app.py", line 1360, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/home/kave/eclipse/F11/Engineering/flask/app.py", line 1358, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/home/kave/eclipse/F11/Engineering/flask/app.py", line 1344, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/home/kave/eclipse/F11/Engineering/f11_app/views.py", line 28, in index
    return render_template('index.html')
  File "/home/kave/eclipse/F11/Engineering/flask/templating.py", line 125, in render_template
    context, ctx.app)
  File "/home/kave/eclipse/F11/Engineering/flask/templating.py", line 107, in _render
    rv = template.render(context)
  File "/home/kave/eclipse/F11/Engineering/jinja2/environment.py", line 969, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/home/kave/eclipse/F11/Engineering/jinja2/environment.py", line 742, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/home/kave/eclipse/F11/Engineering/f11_app/templates/index.html", line 1, in top-level template code
    {% extends "base.html" %}
OSError: [Errno 38] Function not implemented
INFO     2013-06-17 14:26:42,799 server.py:593] default: "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 291
```

Any idea what this could be? Many thanks

Comment: Can you show your templates? Looks like you use some function that is not visible from template context

Comment: I am using mainly two functions: The classic url_for -> `<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js') }}"></script>` and `Flask-Assets` -> 
`{% assets "f11_js" %}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ ASSET_URL }}"></script>
 {% endassets %}`

Comment: I never used assets before, but quick googling point me to this module http://webassets.readthedocs.org/en/latest/integration/jinja2.html make sure that you have installed in your local environment.

Comment: @MikhailKashkin That is correct. I am using http://elsdoerfer.name/docs/flask-assets/ which is a wrapper for web-assets. I wonder if this is allowed/compatible with GAE.  I think this is not allowed, since Flask-Assets needs to minify javascripts at runtime. GAE won't/can't allow that. So I wonder hwo do GAE users minify their css and js? Starting googeling again... :)

Comment: I looked into webasset documentation, generally you cann't use it on GAE. From what I understand it tries to compress static files and put result to static folder. On GAE your static files are hosted on different server. So quick solution will be remove `assets` dependensies. You can compress js/css files before upload to GAE.

Comment: yes you are right. I have to scrap it. You can put this as an answer and I tick it. Now I need to find a good way to automate the minifying on GAE. Thanks

Comment: Aha, sure. Probably you can also rename title of this question to something related to `webassets` (and don't remove `flask` and `gae`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error appeard because Jinja doesn't know about tag `assets` used in template. Second problem is that project supposed to run on GAE with `webasset` python library. But by default it is not working, since `webassets` need output folder to store compressed static files and it is against GAE hosting logic.

Solution is simple: don't use `webassets` in realtime and compress static files before upload to GAE.